# Qu'est-ce que le glissement de niveau par Catford?

Tags: traduction, linguistique

Je ne comprends pas quel est le glissement de niveau parce que je ne trouve pas d'exemple en français.

Alors pour exemple,

- Français: Les fleurs
- Anglais: Flowers

"Les" est un article qui accompagne le nom mais il n'y a pas d'article pour l'équivalent anglais, alors, c'est un glissement de niveau ?

Comment: *glissement*... *catford*... tu veux parler de ce qu'il appelle *shift* ?

Comment: oui, level shift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ton *glissement de niveau* selon Catford correspond à ce qu'il appelle *"level shift"*.

Il le définit lui-même sans ambiguïté : Lorsque à un élément de la langue source appartenant à un niveau de langage donné correspond un élément de la langue cible appartenant à un autre niveau de langage.

Je ne vois pas ce genre de truc **au niveau lexical** dans ton exemple. Pour moi *fleurs* et *flowers* appartiennent au même niveau de langue en anglais et en français. L'absence de l'article ne change rien à la substance.

Si tu cherches des cas de glissement purement lexical, tu peux songer à n'importe quelle traduction par un mot enfantin ou familier ou argotique (*mother*->*maman*, *trousers*->*falzar*, *wine*->*jaja*, *money*->*flouze*...)

Toutefois, Catford ne traite pas de ces cas de glissement lexique à lexique car sa théorie sur la traduction les exclut. Et le fait que ton exemple porte l'attention sur l'article me laisse penser que ce n'est pas cela que tu cherches.

Il ne lui reste que les glissements grammaire <-> lexique. C'est bien à dire que les seuls cas dont il se préoccupe seront dans le cadre d'une phrase complète. Et, dans ce cadre, oui, l'absence d'un article peut témoigner d'un glissement de niveau.
Dans un exemple qu'il prend lui même :

EN : ***This*** may reach you before I arrive -> FR : *Il se peut que **ce mot** vous parvienne avant mon arrivée*

Là, oui, au sens dans lequel Catford le retient on observe ce qu'il appelle glissement de niveau dans la mesure ou L'article *this* va être traduit par non pas son correspondant immédiat *ce* mais par **ce mot**.

On observerait la même chose avec :

EN : ***This*** book is intended for... -> ***Le présent*** manuel s'adresse à...

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Catford reconnaît ces exemples de *glissement de niveau* *plus ou moins complets*. Sa conception précise du *glissement de niveau* grammaire<->lexique est plus largement étoffée dans les cas de traduction Anglais <-> Russe.</sub>

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Dand le cas où tu souhaiterais entrer encore plus précisément dans le sujet, je te recommande de te reporter à https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/</sub>

Comment: Un commentaire comme ça: les traducteurs français ont longtemps péché de l'autre côté → des noms très communs de la langue source deviennent en traduction des termes extrêmement trop littéraires en français. Même récemment, Milan Kundera apprenant le français a pu déplorer ce genre de traitement sur ses textes, qu’il écrivait simplement et qu’il découvrit presque hors de portée des masses en français (ce qui provoqua un blitz de correction de traduction et de retraduction de sa part).

Comment: que diriez-vous des suffixes de genre ou nombre? Comme, "elle est intelligente" qui s'est traduit à "She's intelligent". Le suffixe "-e" est un grammaire, non? mais l'anglais n'a pas comme ça. c'est un glissement di niveau? ou un glissement d'intra-système?

Comment: @user8930 : Pour un adjectif, la marque du genre ou du nombre n'est pas ce que l'on appelle un suffixe. Un suffixe modifie la substance, oui. La substance n'est pas modifiée par la flexion. Absolutely no shift in your example. cont...

Comment: Pour ce qui est du nombre et parce que les systèmes EN/FR correspondent, il n'y aura, en général pas de shift. Il existe effectivement des exceptions. Par ex. quand un singulier EN se traduit par un pluriel FR ou l'inverse comme avec *the contents -> *le contenu*, *dishes / vaisselle* - trousers / pantalon... Dans ces cas, oui alors on peut constater un shift d'intra-système.